# Two dependant date pickers where start date can never be larger than end date

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using the date-reactpicker and have a start and end date/time. It should never be possible to pick a smaller date/time in the starter picker. So the obvious is to set the MinDate and MinTime in the end date picker. However the DatePicker requires you to set both MinTime and MaxTime. And i dont want to set anything in the MaxTime. Any pointers how to solve this?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import DatePicker, { setHours } from "react-datepicker";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
  Button
} from "reactstrap";

const Insights = props => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState();
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState();
  const [endMinDate, setEndMinDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endMinTime, setEndMinTime] = useState(new Date());

  const GetSearchForm = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm();

    const timePickerStyle = { width: 96, important: "true" };

    const onSearch = data => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(startDate);
    };

    const onDateStartChange = date => {
      setStartDate(date);
      setEndMinDate(date);
      setEndMinTime(date);
      alert(date);
    };

    const onDateEndChange = date => {
      setEndDate(date);
    };

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSearch)}>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="exampleEmail">Account Id</Label>
              <Input
                type="number"
                name="account"
                id="account"
                placeholder="AccountId"
                innerRef={register}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="examplePassword">Email</Label>
              <Input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                innerRef={register}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>

          <Col>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="exampleEmail">xPage Id</Label>
              <Input
                type="number"
                name="xpageid"
                id="xpage"
                placeholder="xPage Id"
                innerRef={register}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="examplePassword">Content Devider Id</Label>
              <Input
                type="number"
                name="contentdevider"
                id="contentdeviderid"
                placeholder="Content Devider Id"
                innerRef={register}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="examplePassword">Custom Page Id</Label>
              <Input
                type="number"
                name="custompage"
                id="custompageid"
                placeholder="Custom Page Id"
                innerRef={register}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="examplePassword">Service</Label>
              <Input
                type="text"
                name="servicename"
                id="servicename"
                placeholder="Custom Page Id"
                innerRef={register}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row>
          <Col xs="4">
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="exampleEmail">Start</Label>
              <DatePicker
                isClearable
                innerRef={register}
                name="datetimestart"
                className={"form-control"}
                selected={startDate}
                onChange={date => onDateStartChange(date)}
                showTimeSelect
                timeFormat="HH:mm"
                timeIntervals={15}
                timeCaption="time"
                dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy H:mm"
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col xs="4">
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="exampleEmail">End</Label>
              <DatePicker
                isClearable
                innerRef={register}
                name="datetimeend"
                className={"form-control"}
                selected={endDate}
                onChange={date => onDateEndChange(date)}
                showTimeSelect
                timeFormat="HH:mm"
                timeIntervals={15}
                timeCaption="time"
                dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy H:mm"
                maxDate={startDate}
                minTime={endMinDate}
                maxTime={startDate}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Button>Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col xs="12" lg="12">
        <Card>
          <CardHeader>
            <i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i> Insights
          </CardHeader>
          <CardBody>
            <GetSearchForm></GetSearchForm>
            <div>
              startDate:
              {startDate == null ? "" : startDate.toString()}
            </div>
            <div>endDate:{endDate == null ? "" : endDate.toString()}</div>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default Insights;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the datetime in the onDateEndChange function. For do this you need to:
- remove min and max time props from the end datepicker
- add in the onDateEndChange comparison of start date and end date; if end date will be early or similar - don't update state or update state with minimum date (start date plus one minute, for example).

Comment: But that will only warn me or prevent me from comparison. I want the time and date to be greyed in the picker so people simply cant click on something wrong.

Comment: Try to set max time to 23:59. In any case - you always have min border; max border for every day - is 23:59 (end of day)